# Evitar clientes accedan a fichero, dentro de página web, permitir solo llamadas realizadas dentro del servidor Nginx

Tags: webservice, web, servidor, nginx

Tengo una duda, es posible evitar mediante el bloque server de Nginx u otra herramienta que los usuarios ingresen a una ruta en especifico desde el explorador y solo pueda ser llamada mediante el mismo servidor? 
Por ejemplo tengo las siguientes rutas:

```
public_html/index.php (este acceso disponible para todos desde el explorador)
public_html/procesa.php (este fichero que no esté disponible haciendo en el explorador localhost/procesa.php, solo se ejecute al ser solicitado por index.php)
```

Comment: Puedes usar el Htaccess  pero Creo que seria recomendado que cuando intentas llamar a otro archivo valides el contenido del archivo, Puedes usar Banderas, Token, o simples variables que estén almacenadas en tu DB, asi si intentan ejecutar las funciones almacenadas o escritas en el archivo no podrán por la validación que aplicaste.

Answer (score 0):

En nginx eso se puede hacer de varias formas, una de ellas podría ser :

```
        location /procesa.php {
                allow 127.0.0.1; # tambien puede ser "allow localhost;"
                deny all;
        }
```